What is the meaning of `{userId}` in this Cloud Functions code sample?
I'm reading the documentation of Extend Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions.
The code is as follows
// Listen for changes in all documents in the 'users' collection
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // If we set `/users/marie` to {name: "Marie"} then
      // context.params.userId == "marie"
      // ... and ...
      // change.after.data() == {name: "Marie"}
    });

In functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}'), I don't really understand the {userId}.
I know every collection in firestore has a document ID. I have saved my document ID in the field of every user as UID. So, do I replace the {userId} with my UID or I should just use the {userId} as it it or do I need to use the specific field I want to trigger?
In my case I want to trigger the field time in my document.

The {userId} in the triggering path means that the function is triggered by any document under users, and that the document ID is available in your code as context.params.userId.
If you want to trigger only on a single document, you'd use:
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
    .document('users/marie').onWrite(

But when you use a wildcard as in the example in your question, it triggers on all documents at that path. The more complete example from the linked docs:
// Listen for changes in all documents in the 'users' collection
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // If we set `/users/marie` to {name: "Marie"} then
      // context.params.userId == "marie"
      // ... and ...
      // change.after.data() == {name: "Marie"}
    });

So both of the above examples would trigger when you write to a document at /users/marie. But when you write to a document /users/eben, only the second example will triggered (and context.params.userId will be eben in that scenario).

I'm sorry but it still doesn't answer my question. I'm using a collection called "BOOKS", so do I continue to use it like this "'BOOKS/{userId}'" or what?

The name inside the {...} doesn't matter, it just determines how you can then look it up in the code. So if you have BOOKS, I'd probably use BOOKS/{bookId} and access it as context.params.bookId.
